# google maps android api- customising info window

Tags: android-maps-v2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcZ7m.png)I want a **info window** like this.How can i Do so?

I have tried using **xml drawables**, **background images**, but nothing is helpful.

I want to provide the outline as it is given in the image. I want to use this info window in my google map android application.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be a bit more specific where you want that (within an own app?), what technology you are using and what you have tried so far (including code samples).

Comment: I want to provide the outline/boundries as it is given in the image. I want to use this info window in my google map android application. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a button on a `InfoWindow`. The InfoWindow is automatically converted to an image. You can, however, click on the InfowWindow and have your desired behavior with `setOnInfoWindowClickListener`

Comment: I have used the set
O

Comment: I want to know how to provide the outline/boundary like in the image to the info window. Thanx for the reply.